# action inside li tag does not triggered sometimes in Ember js 1.10

Tags: ember.js

I have multiple tabs in my page which link to some internal routes. When an user clicks on a tab ,the route has to be rendered and also the tab has to be highlighted but once in a few clicks the highlighting does not shift to the new tab and the old tab remains highlighted but the route of the clicked tab gets rendered.

The highlighting is done by an action inside the li tag and the #link-to is nested inside the li tag.

In my investigation till now what I have found is that the when this happens the click event is not registered. I get a bunch of mouse events but no click event. Seems like the click event is eaten up.

```coffee
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
 {{# each tab in tabBars}}
   <li {{action 'someAction'}}>{{#link-to tab.link}}{{/link-to}}</li>
 {{/each}}
</ul>
```

The action should be triggered all times when a tab is click and the new tab should be highlighted.

Answer (score 0):

Try to do something like this instead:

```
{{#link-to tab.link tagName='li'}}click me{{/link-to}}
```

(and omit the `<li>` tag).

Then you can check for the `active` class to highlight the `li` element.

Answer (score 0):

The `{{link-to}}` helper renders a link which will get an additional `class="active"` if the link matches the current route. You can then style this by CSS.

See https://guides.emberjs.com/v1.10.0/templates/links/ and search for "active".

#### Other options

Since the `{{link-to}}` will trigger the `tab.link` route's `beforeModel` hook, perhaps this is the place you might want to set view-related properties to be "data-downed" to the `<li>`. I would personally reserve this hook for business logic.

When I absolutely need to fire an action before transitioning (usually, this is when I want to fire something like a tracking event), I use the `invokeAction` closure action which comes with the [ember-link-action](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ember-link-action) addon although it looks like might only support `1.13.13`

```html
{{link-to invokeAction=(action "someAction")}}
```

#### Best practice

For the action in the `<li>` element you generally want to avoid setting actions on non-interactive elements since it creates an accessibility concern for users of assistive technology (see [no-invalid-interactive](https://github.com/ember-template-lint/ember-template-lint/blob/master/docs/rule/no-invalid-interactive.md)).

However, this doesn't mean you should turn the `<li>` element into an interactive element by doing something link `<li role="button">` as this violates more a11y concerns (see [no-nested-interactive](https://github.com/ember-template-lint/ember-template-lint/blob/master/docs/rule/no-nested-interactive.md)).

Answer (score -2):

I found a solution which does not involve actions:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    {{#each tab in tabs}}
        {{#link-to tab.link id=tab.id tagName='li' }}<a>{{tab.title}}</a>{{/link-to}}
    {{/each}}
</ul>
```

link-to masquerading as li and having a dummy anchor inside it.